# achieve a contract vs win a contract

Tags: meaning, collocation

I am wondering if my understanding of these two phrases is correct. Could you confirm this?

1. make a contract = create a contract
2. achieve a contract = win a contract

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**For no. 1**, more acceptable phrases are:

- enter into [a] contract
  Example:  We must enter into a contract with XYZ Corporation if we want to generate more sales during the next quarter.
- contract with someone (for something) and contract (with someone) for something to make an agreement with someone to produce or supply something, or to do something. I will have to contract with an expert for that part of the project. We contracted with a local builder for a new kitchen. Did you contract for plumbing work with Eric? http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/contract

**For no. 2**, "win [a] contract" is already good or correct. It is more commonly used than 'achieve a contract'.
Example:  I am confident we will win this contract with ABC Company.